LookerStudio expensive PARSE_DATETIME function on DATE column
we have LookerStudio connected with a BigQuery table. The table is partitioned by a DATE column. The LookerStudio creates following query which is expensive (800+ MB billed)
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column >= PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d', '20230909') AND column <= PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d', '20231006')

When i try to update the query manually to following format and run it in BiqQuery, it processes 12 MB.
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column >= '2023-09-09' AND column <= '2023-10-06'

The LookerStudio knows, that the column is data type DATE and that the table is partitioned using the column. I checked checkbox which should tell LookerStudio which column was used to partition BigQuery table. My question is how to force LookerStudio to create more effective queries?
